# HowTo PHPUnit assertFunction

Tags: php, function, phpunit, assert

I was wondering if how I can verify if a 'class' has a Function.
assertClassHasAttribute does not work, it's normal since a Function is not an Attribute.

Comment: why would you want to test that?

Comment: It's useful when I do some refactoring... Having to KNOW, by tests, the methods my classes contain helps when I have to transfert a method into another class for some reasons: like for decoupling responsabilities, etc.

Comment: I'd argue that you will never have a need for this when you just make sure the dependencies are properly mocked/stubbed and you have your public API fully covered.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When there's not an assertion method provided by PHPUnit I either create it or use one of the lower-level assertions with a verbose message:

```
$this->assertTrue(
  method_exists($myClass, 'myFunction'), 
  'Class does not have method myFunction'
);
```

`assertTrue()` is as basic as you can get. It allows a great deal of flexibility because you can use any built-in php function that returns a bool value for your test. Consequently, when the test fails the error/failure message isn't helpful at all. Something like `Failed asserting that <FALSE> is TRUE`. That's why it's important to pass the second param to `assertTrue()` detailing why the test failed.

Answer (score 7):

> Unit and Integration tests are for testing behaviors not for restating
>   what the class definition is.

So PHPUnit doesn't provide such assertion.
PHPUnit can either assert that a class has a name X , that a function returns value somthing , but you can do what you want using :

```
/**
 * Assert that a class has a method 
 *
 * @param string $class name of the class
 * @param string $method name of the searched method
 * @throws ReflectionException if $class don't exist
 * @throws PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException if a method isn't found
 */
function assertMethodExist($class, $method) {
    $oReflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($class); 
    assertThat("method exist", true, $oReflectionClass->hasMethod($method));
}
```

Comment: awesome. this sounds perfect for my need. Thanks @MounaCheikhna