# Assert that class has method

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I just started to use phpunit and I'm wondering why there is no `assertClassHasMethod()`, similar to [`assertClassHasAttribute`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertClassHasAttribute).

I might have missed it, so I'm asking here in hope of enlightenment ☸️.

My current workaround is to use `assertTrue()`, but the error message and manually creating the error message, is not so nice.

```
$this->assertTrue(
    method_exists(Configuration::class, 'all'),
    'Failed asserting that class "' . Configuration::class . '" has method "all".'
);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9448943/4471134

Comment: It's common practice in BDD to first create a unit test, then make the test fail, and then implement the unit. `assertClassHasMethod` is the first method to use, after `assertInstanceOf`. The answer from Mouna Cheikhna seems odd to me.

Comment: I think this is design job to define class. And there are things like `interface` and `abstract` classes which are templates for method design. The reason why PHPUnit has `assertClassHasAttribute` is i think, because in PHP class attributes can be created dynamically and they represent object state, so it actually tests behavior.

Comment: *"why there is no `assertClassHasMethod()`"* -- because the methods are written in the code and not generated during runtime; object properties (attributes) can be set at runtime without the need to declare them in the class definition.